# How to edit my attribute table in ArcGIS with VBA

Tags: attributes, edit, arcgis, arcobjects

before I start you should know that I am a bloody newcomer when it comes down to coding. I am sitting on some university tasks regarding VBA and ArcGIS: My next task is to create a code snippet that enables the user to edit values (rows) in the attribute table. my attribute table consists of points with basic information such as name, address etc. What I would love to do is load a kind of LIST of all rows and be able to click on the specific row I want to edit. Feel free to post easier ways to get there.. as I said I am extremely new to the world of coding ;-)

Thanks everyone

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you're new to programming, but based on what you're saying, I think you're easiest route is using standard out-of-the-box ArcMap functionality.

Even though whatever you're trying to do can be accomplished with VBA (know that in ArcGIS 10 and up, this option is discouraged now), you can already doing the following in ArcMap...

1. Open up the attribute table, and select a row. Use a query definition if you want to narrow it down.
2. If you need to load an external list, ArcGIS already provides numerous ways of importing data into an ArcMap table (like csv files, xls, dbf, oledb, etc).
3. Start the edit session and you can use the Attribute Editor to see a Detail Form editor of your selected features
4. You can now create edit feature templates that allows you to fine tune your edit experience (creating dropdown boxes, etc). All without coding.